# Can't delete (rm -rf) a folder whose name is trailing with a space

Tags: delete

I know this is a questions that comes up quite often, but, even if I googled a lot, I haven't found any solution.

What I would do is

```
$ rm -r 0624\ -\ 5\ Days\ of\ War\ /
```

(tab completion already out [:space] in place of [:space]), but the shell says that the file can't be found.

I have also tried with

```
$ rm -r "0624 - 5 Days of War /"
```

(and      $ rm -r "0624 - 5 Days of War"     for safety.)
But I gave no it didn't worked either.

Does anybody has some suggestion?

Comment: You are dealing with Directory " but the shell says that the file can't be found.". Where are you mentioning file name?  second command is wrong since you are using "" and / you can use either but not both

Comment: [pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/S56ZbdNfJz/plain/)

Comment: try using single quotes. this worked for me - `rmdir '0624 - 5 Days of War '` or `rm -r '0624 - 5 Days of War '`

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

`rmdir 0624\ -\ 5\ Days\ of\ War/`

Comment: Tried: it doesn't work, it still claims that can't find the dir  `rm: impossibile rimuovere '0624 - 5 Days of War /': File o directory non esistente`

Comment: can you specify your dirname precisely or any pastebin from shell

Comment: [pastebin] https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/S56ZbdNfJz/plain/

Comment: directory with spaces would be obviously inside quotes, pastebin file does'nt show that because of grepping the output. try this and this worked for me `rmdir 0624\ -\ 5\ Days\ of\ War/`.I did edit my answer

Comment: if you aren't sure just use autocomplete(tab) feature.it would escape it for you

Answer (score 0):

Your user ID doesn't have write access to the directory:

```
mune@lello:/mnt/media_NAS/Movies$ ls -l1 | grep 0624
drwxr-xr-x 2 mune root 0 apr  4  2018 0624 - 5 Days of War
```

Try using:

```
sudo rm -rf "0624 - 5 Days of War "
```

of if there isn't a trailing space:

```
sudo rm -rf "0624 - 5 Days of War"
```

Comment: I have already tried and now I  try it once again [code] sudo rm -rf "0624 - 5 Day s of War  " [/code :  the commands doesn't return  any error, but it is doing nothing: [code] ls -l1 | grep 0624

drwxr-xr-x 2 mune root 0 apr  4  2018 0624 - 5 Days of War [/code]

Comment: Can you edit your question and copy and paste your terminal screen lines into it? Thanks.

Comment: I think there is already everything. I apologize for the 'sudo' stuff but it was so natural that I haven't mentioned it.